# CSS or JS - Hide an element, while showing an inner element (IE8 only)

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am adding some CSS using Javascript to one page only (I can't use JQUERY)

I have this **HTML code : I can't edit it:**

```
<td><label for="7">test1 </label>test2</td>
```

**I want to hide "test2" but show "test1"**

Currently I have: "td visible:none; td label visible: yes"

**and it works for every browser except IE8** (it hides everything, even if !important is added to the showing of the label tag, which is added second, so should have greater priority

```
addCss("form table.standard td{visibility: hidden;}form table.standard input,form table.standard label,form table.standard b,form table.standard font.red{visibility: visible !important;}");
```

I can add different CSS for IE8 using javascript, but I couldn't find or think of what to do..

All the code on GoogleDocs if you want to see it/ do something similar http://goo.gl/9xeCqt

Comment: /edit/ someone asked if you can make an element in an invisible one visible (and then deleted the comment) /edit/ : 

Yes ~ It works on the latest Chrome, FireFox, IE 6,7,10,11

Comment: How could you hide parent and show its child?

Comment: @Era [It works in all browsers I tested except IE8 {Chrome, FireFox, IE 6,7,10,11}] addCss("form table.standard td{visibility: hidden;}form table.standard input,form table.standard label,form table.standard b,form table.standard font.red{visibility: visible !important;}");

Comment: it could be.. but this is not the optimized way to get the result.

Comment: @Era Ah, indeed? This series of 4 pages will not receive that much traffic, so optimization isn't the most important thing for me, just mainly getting it to work in IE8

Answer (score 0):

you can give the tag elements to both value (test1,test2) and you can give class to both elements and apply css for each like :

```
<td><label for="7" class="first">test1 </label><label class="second">test2</label></td>
```

and apply like :

td .second visible:none; td .first visible: yes"

Comment: he cant chang/ modify html.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JayDeep Nimavat - cant change HTML

Comment: yes but for that, this is only way that edit to html.

Comment: @JayDeepNimavat - It works in all browsers except IE8, so hopefully it's not impossible... Thanks anyway~~

Comment: // in head
    <!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

// in css
    ie8.yourclass/tag{
        // your style here.
    }

this is conditional way to apply for different css for ie8 in same css file

Comment: @JayDeepNimavat I know how to add CSS just for IE8 (I have it written in the Google Docs file linked to from the post) - All I need is the CSS which will fulfill the required function ~ [Note: I have different CSS added for IE8 using javascript]